# JButton Tooltip doesn't work when buttons are added to a JPanel

Tags: swing, tooltip, jbutton

So I'm new in Java Swing. And I created a JFrame and then a JPanel in the frame. I added the buttons to the Panel which is then added to the frame. But when I create the tooltip like
         button.addToolTipText("here's your tip");

But it doesn't show when I run it.
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You need to show some snippets of the code so we can see what you are doing.

Comment: and it is setToolTipText("Your Tool Tip")

Answer (score -1):

Tooltips only display when you hover your mouse over the component for a given period of time. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tool Tips](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tooltip.html) for a working example.

> Am I doing something wrong?

We can't tell based on one line of code. If you still need more help after using the demo programs then post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.